# An error has occurred (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am having an issue with a cloud code function. The function is called from an iOS app written in Swift. What I'm trying to do is send "customer.id" to Parse. However, I get the error:

> An error has occurred (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)

**Cloud Code**

```
function stripeCreateP(params) {
var p = new Parse.Promise();
stripe.customers.create(params, function(err, customer) {
    if (err) {
        p.resolve(customer);
    } else {
        p.reject(err);
    }
});
return p;
}

Parse.Cloud.define("customer", function(request, response) {
 // Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var user = request.user; 
stripeCreateP({ email: request.params.useremail}).then(function(customer) {
    user.set("cusToken", customer.id);
    return user.save();
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(customer);
console.log(customer.id);
    response.success(customer); 
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.error(err);
});
});
```

**Swift**

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("customer", withParameters: ["useremail": self.userEmailAdressTextField.text ?? ""], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: Recommend you point to which line of code is failing.

Comment: @JamesJones it doesn't say, but I think it has to do with the line `    user.set("cusToken", customer.id);` particularly with `customer.id`. I don't think it's retrieving it.